# Application asking twice to exit with onBackPressed()

Tags: android

I have used following method to exit the application by prompting alertbox to user.
But my application is asking 2 times to leave.

Code:

```
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed()
    {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Closing Activity")
        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to close this activity?")
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();    
                }
            })
        .setNegativeButton("No", null)
        .show();
    }
```

Comment: Do you `Override` the `finish()` method? Also, I will say that this is a bad idea , IMHO, unless absolutely necessary such as saving data

Comment: have you override onkeydown also?

Comment: give your whole activity or show if you override on destroy() or finish() method

Comment: Print a stacktrace whenever you bring up the dialog to see what caused it to trigger each time. Btw, agree with codeMagic - I would install an app that prompts me when I pressed the back button. Yes, I want to close the activity, that's why I pressed the back button!

Comment: There's one app I have to use that asks me if I want to quit.  I hate it!  If I didn't want to quit, I wouldn't have pressed back.  Just don't do this.  It's anti mobile and Android app design.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This could be the result of several things:

1. You have also overridden `void onKeyDown(...)` or `void dispatchKeyEvent(...)`
   and call `onBackPressed();` in there
2. you have overridden `void finish()`
   and there you call the second dialog
3. your app is instanciated 2 times
   (for any reason -- see your code?)
4. you open your activity with an intent twice intentionally, then I have a fix here :)
   replace your code to open it with this piece:

   ```
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, yourSubActivityClass.class);
   intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
   startActivity(intent);
   ```

   From the documentation:

   > If set, and the activity being launched is already running in the current task, then instead of launching a new instance of that activity, all of the other activities on top of it will be closed and this Intent will be delivered to the (now on top) old activity as a new Intent.
5. if some of those helped you, please tell me in the comments
   otherwise post more code, and I will try to help you more ;)

Comment: Thanks you @Schnizel1337 it works i removed Override from OnBackPressed method and cleared the top. It works fine now..Thank you very much...!!!!

Comment: no problem, then you can accept my answer with the button on the left, so others can see it was correct :)

Answer (score 0):

```
//I use this : 

public class MyActivity extends Activity
    {
    private int BackPressedCount=0; //press count

    private void StartTimer()
        {
        TimerTask TT=new TimerTask() 
            {
            @Override
            public void run() 
                {
                try
                    {
                    //if second press not detect in 1 second,reset and stop timer
                    BackPressedCount=0; 
                    this.cancel();
                    }
                catch(Exception E)
                    {
                    }
                }
            };
        new Timer().scheduleAtFixedRate(TT, 1000, 1000);// init timer for 1 second period
        }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() 
        {
        //super.onBackPressed();

        BackPressedCount++; //every press

        if(BackPressedCount==1) // if first press detect run Timer (wait for second press)
            StartTimer();

        if(BackPressedCount==2) // if second press detect then finish
            finish();   

        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"Press again to exit" ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Can you add some explanation or comments to help clarify your answer?